# Is there a way to force ember to always use plural

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, inflector

I've been looking around and couldn't find a way to do it except with:

```
var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;

inflector.uncountable('news');
inflector.uncountable('rules');
```

Declaring for each my model is a bit cumbersome and I would like to know if there's a way to make it more general.

Finally what is the reason for using english grammar as a rule for inflection? And what is inflection supposed to provide?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a framework which doesn't think you should do everything its way and wants to run your life.

Comment: I generally like conventions over configuration. Though I think this is a bad convention and I'd like to get rid of it...